# How do I stop ads interrupting my music player

Tags: samsung, audio, ads

I have a Galaxy Note 9 where I usually have music playing in Amazon Music Player in the background while I play games. In the old version of the OS (Samsung's version Android 8.1) when I am playing a game and an advert starts, it would pause the music, but I could just slide down the notification area and unpause it. Since the recent upgrade to Android 9 (again Samsung's version which it automatically upgraded to), I have to wait until the advert has finished before I can unpause the music. This is ultra annoying!

I don't mind the advert, or even the advert playing its sounds while the music is in the background, but completely taking over the sound like this just wrong!

So is there a setting or app-permission or anything I can change to disable ads from stealing exclusive access to the audio?

Comment: Are you against using a third-party apps to disable ads, such as through an ad-blocker?

Comment: If it comes to that, then I don't mind installing them.

Answer (score 3):

Open the Google Settings app on your device (called Google Settings or Settings, depending on your device).
Scroll down and tap Google.
Tap Ads.
Turn on Opt out of interest-based ads or Opt out of Ads Personalization.
Reset the ad id, or user id.

This is the only thing I've been able to find on the subject.  Like you, I run a background app while doing other things and, knock on plastic and glass, it seems to have worked
I have an S10+, but it should be the same on your note

Comment: This would not affect sound in ads so not help to stop ads to mute music.

Answer (score 2):

If adblock is an option, I highly recommend Blokada. It is a local VPN that uses host files to block ads and can work without root. More info [here](https://blokada.org). (I am not affiliated with it). It sounds easiest just to block the ads

However, there is no way to keep an app from stealing audio focus that I am aware of.